# protobuf common.h "No such file"

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe

I am trying to install Caffe, and I am running into this frustrating error. When I run `make` I get the following:

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:5:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:9:42: fatal error: google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1
```

I am using the Google protocol buffer 2.6.1 (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads), and I have indeed added the directory to the PATH. The common.h file is definitely there in the directory (I see it with my own eyes), but somehow it is unable to detect it. I have no clue what to do, and all the solutions from [this issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/19) don't seem to work for me.

Any insight would be appreciated. I suspect I am neglecting a step somewhere, as I am rather new to Linux.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

`PATH` tells your shell where to search for commands. It does not tell your compiler where to search for headers. To tell your compiler to find headers in a particular directory, you need to use the `-I` flag. For example:

```
g++ -I/path/to/protobuf/include -c my-source.cc
```

You will need to convince your build system to add this flag to the compiler command-line. All reasonable build systems have some way to do this, but the details vary. For autoconf you can specify when you run configure:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=-I/path/to/protobuf/include
```

For cmake I think you can do something like this (not tested):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/path/to/protobuf/include
```

Alternatively, you would probably not have this problem if you installed protobuf to the standard location -- either `/usr` or `/usr/local` (hence placing the headers in `/usr/include/google/protobuf` or `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf`).

Also note that almost all Linux distributions have a Protobuf package, and you should probably use that rather than installing Protobuf from source code. You will need the `-dev` or `-devel` package in order to get headers. On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. stubs is simply not present in the default install of proto3.

Comment: @PKivolowitz Eh? google/protobuf/stubs/common.h is definitely still there and installed: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/Makefile.am#L85 (And anyway, OP explicitly said they were using 2.6.1.)

Comment: This will install protoc 3.0.0, which is very old. I would strongly advice to build the new version 24.3 or higher. For me, the optional parameter is important and not in version 3. Read https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases for details.

Comment: @BartMensfort What "will install protoc 3.0.0"? My apt-get command? Only if you are using an extremely old distro. On Debian 12 the protobuf package is v21.12 -- a year old, but not 7 years old. Of course if you want the absolute latest features you need to install from source, but most people will be fine with what their package manager gives them.

Comment: Debian 12 is from December 2023, which is installing new version 21. I use Ubuntu 18.04, which is installing version 3. I prefer to limit the versions at my customers. So I am forced to build from source-files. But that's not a big problem in Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is past end-of-life, no longer receiving security patches. You really need to update, you are putting your customers at risk. (And Debian 12 was released in June, not December. 12.4, a minor update, was released in December.)